# changing value of a variable in python tkinter

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

I have just started using python tkinter and i can't get a button to change a date in datetime. So far I have the button changing the value variables b, c, and d but it doesn't change the date. Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
window = Tk()
b = int(1999)
c = int(2)
d = int(2)
today = datetime.date.today()
def changeVariable():
    global b, c, d
    b = int(1914)
    print("changed b")
    c = int(7)
    print("changed c")
    d = int(28)
    print("changed d")

def printVariable():
    global a
    print(a.days)

dog = datetime.date(b, c, d)
a = today - dog
button1 = Button(window, command = changeVariable)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(window, command = printVariable)
button2.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, `changeVariable` *does* change the variables `b`, `c`, and `d`. It's just `a` is calculated before that. Python, and most programming languages for that matter, work in a way that when you say `x = y`, unless special case, doesn't mean that:

> x is equal to y at all times. (pass by reference)

but rather:

> put y's this very instant value to x (pass by value)

so  you should rather put:

```
dog = datetime.date(b, c, d)
a = today - dog
```

in your `printVariable` so that `a`'s value also gets updated.

Your final `printVariable` should be similar to:

```
def printVariable():
    global a
    dog = datetime.date(b, c, d)
    a = today - dog
    print(a.days)
```